# Print nested dictionary in python and export all on a csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{'https://github.com/project1': {'Batchfile': '91', 'Gradle': '110', 'INI': '25', 'Java': '1879', 'Markdown': '393', 'QMake': '52', 'Shell': '161', 'Text': '202', 'XML': '943'}}
{'https://github.com/project2': {'Batchfile': '91', 'Gradle': '123', 'INI': '25', 'Java': '1305', 'Markdown': '121', 'QMake': '52', 'Shell': '161', 'XML': '234'}}
{'https://github.com/project3': {'Batchfile': '91', 'Gradle': '360', 'INI': '27', 'Java': '805', 'Markdown': '27', 'QMake': '156', 'Shell': '161', 'XML': '380'}}
```

It is a structured in this way:

```
{'url': {'lang1': 'locs', 'lang2': 'locs', ...}}
{'url2': {'lang6': 'locs', 'lang5': 'locs', ...}}
```

where lang stay for languages and locs stay for line of codes (related to the previous language).

What i want to do is print this dictionary in a pretty way,so i can see the results before the export.
After that i want to export the dictionary into a csv file to make other operation. The problem is the languages are not sorted. That is what i mean:

```
{'https://github.com/Project4': {'HTML': '29', 'Java': '229', 'Markdown': '101', 'Maven POM': '88', 'XML': '62'}}
{'https://github.com/Project5': {'Batchfile': '85', 'Gradle': '84', 'INI': '22', 'Java': '2422', 'Markdown': '25', 'Prolog': '25', 'Shell': '173', 'XML': '3243', 'YAML': '43'}}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you mean to say that the languages are not printing in sorted order while you use print function? Python dict, or any dict/hash for that matter won't guarantee elements in sorted order. You can use sort function to sort it.

Comment: After sorting it how i can print it pretty and export as csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

t = [{'https://github.com/project1': {'Batchfile': '91', 'Gradle': '110', 'INI': '25', 'Java': '1879', 'Markdown': '393', 'QMake': '52', 'Shell': '161', 'Text': '202', 'XML': '943'}},
{'https://github.com/project2': {'Batchfile': '91', 'Gradle': '123', 'INI': '25', 'Java': '1305', 'Markdown': '121', 'QMake': '52', 'Shell': '161', 'XML': '234'}},
{'https://github.com/project3': {'Batchfile': '91', 'Gradle': '360', 'INI': '27', 'Java': '805', 'Markdown': '27', 'QMake': '156', 'Shell': '161', 'XML': '380'}}]


columns = set([lang for x in t for l in x.values() for lang in l])
index = [p for x in t for p in x.keys()]
rows = [l for x in t for l in x.values() ]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=columns, index=index).fillna('N/A')

df.to_csv('projects.csv')
```

Which gives:

```
>>> df
                            Gradle INI Markdown  ... Batchfile  Java QMake
https://github.com/project1    110  25      393  ...        91  1879    52
https://github.com/project2    123  25      121  ...        91  1305    52
https://github.com/project3    360  27       27  ...        91   805   156

[3 rows x 9 columns]
```

And in the csv:

[image]